# If a random variable is defined over a finite support (say [0,1]), must its variance be finite?

Tags: probability, statistics

As the title goes, if a random variable is defined over a finite support (say [0,1]), is its variance always finite? If not, can anyone help give a counterexample?

Comment: The support has to be closed?  If not, I think of $\tan(U)$, where $U \sim {\cal U}(-\pi,\pi)$.

Comment: @GNUSupporter:  I think the OP means that if the domain has finite support, and there is a density function $f(x)$ defined on that support, must its variance be always finite.  The answer is *yes*.  Even delta functions at the bounds of the domain lead to a finite variance.

Comment: As this answer states, the maximum variance under these conditions is $0.25$.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426426/variance-of-random-variable?rq=1

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I confused set-theoretic support with the measure-theoretic one.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork - on your first comment, there does not need to be a density function, just a cumulative distribution function. Indeed for a random variable on $[0,1]$ with a variance of exactly $0.25$, it does not have a density function

Comment: @Henry:  The variance for $f(x) = 1/2 (\delta (x) + \delta(x-1))$ would be $0.25$, even though a $\delta$-function does not satisfy all properties of a (traditional) function.